# SSRS - Aggregate Total of MAX field in row groups & column groups

Tags: reporting-services

I'm working with a data set to show customer margins (product) before & after freight costs.

I have just about everything working, but I am stumped on how to do freight correctly. My boss wants Freight to appear as a column rather than a row.

I have my dataset as such:

Customer # | CustomerName| FiscalYear | FiscalMonth | Itemcode | Revenue | Cogs | Freight | [RN]

In my report, my row group is CustomerNo
My column group is FiscalMonth  (I'm doing a pivot with SSRS)

For Freight, I am using MAX(FREIGHT) since freight is the same for every item for a customer in a fiscal month. I used MAX since Distinct isn't an option in SSRS. This appears to be working for individual customers and fiscal month appropriately.

Where I am stuck, is how to get the SUM(MAX(FREIGHT)) for the fiscal month of all Customers (Grand Total) as well as the grand total for a customer for all fiscal months. For the grand total, I've tried several variations of =sum(Max(Fields!Freight.Value,"FiscalMonth"),"CustomerNo") or =sum(Max(Fields!Freight.Value,"CustomerNo"),"FiscalMonth") and keep getting errors like:
"The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox13.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset."

"The Value expression for the text box Textbox uses both row and column scopes or scopes from two different data axes in the same aggregate expression.  All nested aggregate functions must specify a named scope along the same data axis as the scope of the containing aggregate."

I've done some searching and keep trying to adjusting my expression but cannot seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue before and ended up writing a function to add the unique values. The data is sent as a single field with a Pipe | separating the values. It then checks to see if a customer is unique and adding the value if so.

```
FUNCTION SUMCustomers(BYVAL ITEMS AS OBJECT()) AS DECIMAL
'Returns Sum of unique Customers. Use as Code.SUMCustomers(Customer & "|" & Amount)
IF ITEMS IS NOTHING THEN 
    RETURN NOTHING
    GOTO EXITSUB
END IF

DIM TEMP AS STRING
DIM Customers AS STRING = ""
DIM Customer AS STRING = ""
DIM VALUE AS DECIMAL 

FOR EACH ITEM AS OBJECT IN ITEMS

    TEMP = CONVERT.TOSTRING(ITEM)

    Customer = "|" & LEFT(TEMP, InStr(TEMP, "|"))

    VALUE = CDEC(MID(TEMP, InStr(TEMP, "|") + 1, LEN(TEMP)))

    IF InStr(Customers, Customer) = 0 Then  
        Customers = Customers + Customer 
        SUMCustomers = SUMCustomers + VALUE
    End If

NEXT

EXITSUB:
END FUNCTION
```

The expression for your issue would be something like

```
=Code.SUMCustomers(Fields!CustomerNo.Value & "|" & Fields!Freight.Value)
```